# Android layout inflator cannot be used?

Tags: android

I am stuck in a small problem. I am unable to use LayoutInflator, when i try to create an instance of it, I get this error known as Cannot resolve this symbol. Can any one please tell me why is it That i am unable to use Layout inflator. And my activity extends AppCompatActivity.

Any help appreciated !
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried when you got that error? Did you try this `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);` or simply `LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();`

Comment: Please share your code that you have tried.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I was just trying to create an instance of LayoutInflator

Comment: I had just tried this > LayoutInflator inflator; I just declared it globally. just after that i could not import any thing by clicking alt + enter. It just displayed cannot resolve this symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Class.this);
```